# Monthly Payments in C, Issue with Variables and Outputs

Tags: c

This is my first time here and I'm having issues writing a a program. I am trying to get monthly payments and salary returned, with different print statements depending on the size of the salary and car payments. However, my output is not coming out correctly. I am receiving a .2f as the output variables, instead of the variables that I want. Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>



int main() {
    float cost;
    float interest;
    int years;
    float salary;
    float sal_twenty;
    float payment;
    float IM;
    float NumMon;

    printf("Enter annual income > ");
    scanf("%f", &salary);

    printf("Enter cost of car > ");
    scanf("%f", &cost);

    printf("Enter annual interest rate > ");
    scanf("%f", &interest);

    printf("Enter duration of loan in years > ");
    scanf("%d", &years);

    sal_twenty = salary * .2;
    IM = interest/12;
    NumMon=years*12;
    payment = cost * (IM * pow((IM + 1), NumMon))/(pow((IM + 1), NumMon) - 1);

    if (payment*12 > sal_twenty) {
        printf("A monthly payment of ");
        printf(".2f", payment);
        printf(" is too high given your annual income of ");
        printf(".2f", &salary);
    }

    if (payment*12 <= sal_twenty) {
        printf("Your annual income of ");
        printf(".2f", salary);
        printf(" allows a monthly payment of ");
        printf(".2f", payment);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [We close all the typo questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions)

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the `%` in the `printf` formats. I.e.

```
printf("%.2f", payment);
```

et cetera. (As you did correctly for `scanf`)

Answer (score 2):

In this `printf(".2f", &salary);` should be

```
printf("%.2f", salary);
```

i.e no `&` before `salary`.